# react native embed video not working

Tags: java, android, iframe, react-native, embed

It's a known issue for react native webview doesn't handle video playback well.

I found that in this discussion https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6405 and https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6603 the WebChromeClient() has been implemented in WebView.
But I still can't to make it work. All I get is black screen. I have try with html source as well as uri, neither of them works.

I also found this https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-webview-android which could possible can solve this problem. But the drawback of this module is that it doesn't support fullscreen playback. This is not really what I want.

I have no Java background,I really don't know how to make it work. Is there other method to embed video in RN? The video source is not limited to youtube, but other streaming service like vimeo and dailymotion.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [`react-native-video`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video) or other libraries that you might find [here](https://js.coach/react-native/react-native-media-player?search=video).

Comment: i have tried this, but installing is a mess and the documentation is outdated. It says we need to edit the MainApplication.java where there are no more addPackage() in the file.

Comment: Have you used rnpm?

Comment: Yes, I did. And there are also complaint by the user that it can't play youtube video. And indeed, it is not working when I try to embed youtube url.

Comment: Hm I don't know if this is still happening but it's possible rnpm still has a bug with appropriately linking new packages for Android. It is possible that YouTube doesn't like you linking their videos directly.

Comment: Not only youtube, source from other streaming site also not working. I also tried manual install. But again in MainActivity.java, there are no more addPackage() there. I think I might have some installation error. But the documentation has no info about this at all.